# LM7915 delivering more than -15v

Tags: power-supply, lm78xx

I'm trying to build a regulated power adapter using LM7915.

Before everything, I built on a protoboard the schema included on the datasheet ([from ST](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000450.pdf)). But, instead -15v, the output is -19v...

I'm using a 18+18v/500mA transformer. After the diode bridge (1n4007) the measure is -17.7v.

Into the input (-Vi) I'm using an electrolitic capacitor of 2200uF (50v). And into the output (-Vo) I'm using an electrolitic capacitor of 10uF (63v).

After wiring everything, measuring pins 1 (ground) and 3 (out) my voltmeter shows -19v...

I did the same experiment with a LM7815 and it worked nicely, so I don't think that I missed something.

Please, could you advise how to debug the circuit? Or point me out what I did wrong?

EDIT (solution?):

I managed to solve(?) the problem. I did not posted it as an answer since I don't know if it's only a coincidence or not... I've attached a picture.

The "problem" was that I wired the transformer 0V to the 7915 ground (pin 1). As you can see into the picture, the transformer has 3 wires: 2 purple and 1 black. Measuring each purple with the black, I found 19vAC, and after the bridge, -18vDC. So, as instructed [here](http://www.robometricschool.com/2013/02/symmetric-power-supply-15v-0-15v.html), [here](http://powersupplycircuit-basicdiagram.blogspot.com.br/2013/08/symmetric-15-volt-power-supply.html), [here](http://www.electronica-pt.com/circuitos/pt/fonte-alimentacao/15-12v-and-15v-symmetric-power-supply.html) and [here](http://www.eleccircuit.com/power-supply-regulator-15v-15v-1a-by-ic-7815-7915/), I did the same on my circuit...

But, when I removed the  ground wire, I got the correct measures: The 7915 pin 2 (in) showed -19vDC and pin 3 (out) -15vDC (in fact a little bit more, close to -16vDC). If I put it again, the measures goes back to the values that I informed before...

[image]

Comment: Check the pinout of the 7915 - the 7815 and 7915 regulators have different pinouts. Also, if the input to the regulator (output of rectifier) is -17.7 volts, you can't possibly have -19 volts at the output of the regulator.

Comment: Thanks @PeterBennett. I edit the post to include the complete measures. I noticed that measuring the capacitor terminals (the one wired to the IN) it showed -28vDC. Regarding the pins, I'm following the datasheet (I'm aware about the differences between 78xx and 79xx). I do not changed it yet because I'm afraid to burn it...

Comment: Add another output capacitor in case the one you're using is open (the 7915, unlike the 7815 may not be stable without an output capacitor of the proper characteristics). If the reading is the same (-19V)- where did that 7915 come from? Not an eBay or Aliexpress purchase, I hope?

Answer (score 1):

Im am assuming that you have checked your pinouts and that your circuit is the one [here](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000450.pdf).

The only thing that I noticed different from your circuit and the data sheet was the value of the caps on the input/output of the regulator.

That being said the values should not make a difference but have you tried using smaller values just to eliminate all possibilities?

Also do you have another multimeter to double check the values that you have measured?

Comment: Yes, the circuit hyperlink is correct. That's the one. I did as you suggested, replacing the 2200uF for smaller caps (22, 100, 220) but the result was the same. Unfortunately I don't have another multimeter, but I have other power sources (including negative ones) and it works right. I also replaced the LM7915, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the single -15 volt supply, I believe you have wired your circuit incorrectly.

If your transformer has an 18V-0-18V secondary, that means that you have 36 volts, RMS, across the purple wires and 18 volts, RMS from the center-tap (the black wire) to either of the purple wires. Expect higher in both cases if there's no load on the transformer.

Then, if you full-wave rectify and filter the 36 volts you'll wind up with about 49 volts DC across the filter cap since DC = RMS \$ \sqrt{2} \$, which is about 51 volts, but then you need to subtract about 2 volts max for the diodes in the bridge, which brings you to 49 volts across the cap, which I don't think the 7915 is going to be too happy about since the cap sits across its input.

Shown below is an easy way to get what you want and not give the 7915 fits. ;)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I dont Know if you solved this problem, but is normal out more than -15V when dont acoplade to charging circuit. Just you to create a circuit with LED and a resistor 1k2, you will see out around -14,8v ou 15,2v. Try it!
Some LM79xx there are this CHARACTERISTICS, especially when you used to diode bridge and the center tape.

I hope help you!